# How to get the coordinates of a GtkTreeView row

Tags: gtk, gtktreeview

I'm using a GtkTreeView widget. If I have a row's GtkTreeIter, how can I then get that row's current position (vertical pixel coordinate) within the entire GtkTreeView window?

My underlying problem is that I need to get a GtkTreeIter for whatever row is currently placed at a given vertical coordinate relative to the entire GtkTreeView window, but I don't know how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function:

```
gtk_tree_view_get_path_at_pos (GtkTreeView        *tree_view,
                               gint                x,
                               gint                y,
                               GtkTreePath       **path,
                               GtkTreeViewColumn **column,
                               gint               *cell_x,
                               gint               *cell_y)
```

will give you a path that you can pass to

```
gtk_tree_model_get_iter()
```

to get an iterator.